# Algorithm to visualise data (multidimensional scaling?) in PHP project

Tags: php, algorithm, data-visualization, multi-dimensional-scaling

I have small matrix of +-100 points/values, results of test and their distances (0-10, 10 is the closest) to each other: http://vis.arcs.cz.

I would like to visualize it in 2D to quickly find a groups of close values. So I need to process this matrix and get the coordinates of points in 2D.

The way is propably multidimensional scaling but I wasnt able to find an algorithm, library or extension nor use the math formulas into PHP code.

Im googling last two days and the closest results of it is
http://www.php.net/manual/en/lapack.leastsquaresbysvd.php - ? 
(cant share more links as novice)

I'll be grateful for any solution applicable in php project (compiled MathLab code in C++...).

Comment: please post a sample json_encoded data and your ideal visualization

Comment: What do you want on x and y axis? As far as i can tell, you have 3 dimensions and not 2 (horizontal matrix position, vertical matrix position, value). Do you want to find pairs with high value, or do you want to find groups, where each pair has high value?

Comment: http://vis.arcs.cz/json_encoded_data.txt

Comment: Hi, thanks, here is json_encode matrix, two-dimensional array, each with each point: http://vis.arcs.cz/json_encoded_data.txt.

Ideal result: http://vis.arcs.cz/ggobi.jpg.

Axis are virtual, without meaning, helping only visualise distances between point (I expect groups of points). This looks to me so close what I need: http://gastonsanchez.com/blog/how-to/2013/01/23/MDS-in-R.html

Comment: Maybe the code of mathlab (R)cmdscale function (what I also couldnt find) could be rewriten directly into php... ?

Comment: This is data mining, not data visualization. The task you are describing is way beyond the scope of an answer. I recommend you read about [Cluster analyzis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis), also try searching for non-metric similarity and non-metric clustering. If you want to dirty your hand, i recommend using a free data-mining tool. Data mining algorithm are usually ones u dont want to implement unless u have to (or you are a masochist).

Comment: Thanks Kicsi, sorry for inaccuracy, in the begining it seemed like a simple task. And still I hope its feasible. There is only really small sample of data with invariant structure (so I found it ridiculous named it data-mining). If there is a tool which can be used in web project - ? I have not found such.

Comment: http://vis.arcs.cz/mds-result-of-test-129.jpg - this is a result obtained from my sample data through xlstat using (similarity/disimilarity matrices and) mds scaling - exactly what I need.

Comment: But I need it online.

Answer (score 0):

```
index.php:

<?php
require("data.php");
require("Mds.php");
$mds = new Mds();
$mds->prepareData($data);
//cislo udava pocet iteraci algoritmu,
//idealne by melo mit hodnotu pocetUzlu na druhou, prakticky muze byt o dost mensi, 5 az 10 krat pocet uzlu.
$mds->scale(100);
//mira splneni podminek - vraci cislo < mensi nez 1. Cim blizsi k 1, tim lepe vyhovuji vzdalenosti
//z vypocteneho rozlozeni zadanym vzdalenostem.
//v nemetrickych datech ovsem dochazi rychle k poklesu az do zapornych hodnot, protoze ve 2D neexistuje
//pro nektere body zadne spravne misto.
echo $mds->getRSquared();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
{
title:{
text: "MDS",
fontFamily: "arial black",
fontColor: "black"
},
axisX: {
title:"",
titleFontFamily: "arial"

},
axisY:{
title: "",
titleFontFamily: "arial",
titleFontSize: 12
},

data: [
{
type: "scatter",
toolTipContent: "<span style='"'color: {color};'"'><strong>{name}</strong></span> x: {y}, y: {y}",
dataPoints:

<?php
echo $mds->printCoords('{x: %X, y: %Y, name: "%LABEL"}');
?>
}]
});

chart.render();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 600px; width: 600px;">
</div>

<a href="mds.zip">mds.zip</a>
</body>
</html>


data.php:



$data = array( 
array ("Jablko", "Voda", 2),
array("Jablko", "Ohen", 7),
array("Jablko", "Cervena", 3),
array("Jablko", "Zelena", 2),

array("Voda", "Ohen", 8),
array("Voda", "Cervena", 8),
array("Voda", "Zelena", 2),

array("Ohen", "Cervena", 1),
array("Ohen", "Zelena", 5),

array("Cervena", "Zelena", 3)
);


Mds.php:

<?php

class Mds {
//node - pole tvaru [[x, y, label], ...]
public $nodes = array();

//tvaru [source][target]=distance
public $givenDistances = array();
public $currentDistances = array();


public function prepareData($data) {
$nodesMap = array();
$xxxx = 10000;
$xxx= 1000;

// $xxxx = 5000;
// $xxx = 600;

foreach($data as $link) {
$source = $link[0];
$target = $link[1];
if(!isset($nodesMap[$source])) {
$nodesMap[$source] = true;
$this->nodes[]=array((float) rand(1,$xxxx) / $xxx, (float) rand(1,$xxxx) / $xxx, $source);
}
if(!isset($nodesMap[$target])) {
$nodesMap[$target] = true;
$this->nodes[]= array((float) rand(1,$xxxx) / $xxx, (float) rand(1,$xxxx) / $xxx, $target);
}
}
//vytvori matici pro ulozeni vzdalenosti
foreach($this->nodes as $node) {
$this->givenDistances[$node[2]] = array();
$this->currentDistances[$node[2]] = array();
}
foreach($data as $link) {
$source = $link[0];
$target = $link[1];
$distance = $link[2];
$this->givenDistances[$source][$target] = $distance;
$this->givenDistances[$target][$source] = $distance;
}
}

protected function countCurrentDistances() {
$mean = 0;
$i = 0;

foreach($this->nodes as $nodeA) {
foreach($this->nodes as $nodeB) {
$dist = sqrt(($nodeB[0]-$nodeA[0])*($nodeB[0]-$nodeA[0]) + ($nodeB[1]-$nodeA[1])*($nodeB[1]-$nodeA[1]));
$this->currentDistances[$nodeA[2]][$nodeB[2]] = $dist;

if($nodeA[2]!==$nodeB[2]) {
$mean += $this->givenDistances[$nodeA[2]][$nodeB[2]];
}
}
}
// echo "<pre>";
// var_dump($this->currentDistances);
// echo "</pre>";
$check = array();

$nodesCount = count($this->nodes);
$this->mean = $mean/($nodesCount*$nodesCount);
}

public function getRSquared() {
$this->countCurrentDistances();

$sum = 0;
$SStot = 0;
$SSres = 0;
foreach($this->nodes as $nodeA) {
foreach($this->nodes as $nodeB) {
$aLab = $nodeA[2];
$bLab = $nodeB[2];
if($aLab===$bLab) {
continue;
}

$given = $this->givenDistances[$aLab][$bLab];
$computed = $this->currentDistances[$aLab][$bLab];

$SSres+=(($given-$computed)*($given-$computed));
$SStot+= ($given-$this->mean)*($given-$this->mean);
}
}

return 1 - ($SSres/$SStot);
}

protected function iterate($inverseCoefStrenth=1) {
for($i=0; $i<count($this->nodes); $i++) {
$nodeA = $this->nodes[$i];
$move = array(0,0);
$moves = 0;

for($j=0; $j<count($this->nodes); $j++) {
if($j===$i) {
continue;
}

$nodeB = $this->nodes[$j];
$dist = $this->givenDistances[$nodeA[2]][$nodeB[2]];

$AB = array($nodeB[0]-$nodeA[0], $nodeB[1]-$nodeA[1]);
$lAB = sqrt(($AB[0]*$AB[0])+($AB[1]*$AB[1]));

$coef = ($lAB - $dist)/$lAB;

$AA1 = array($AB[0]*$coef, $AB[1]*$coef);

$moves++;
$move[0]+=$AA1[0];
$move[1]+=$AA1[1];
}

if($moves>0) {
$resultingMoveX = $move[0]/($moves*$inverseCoefStrenth);
$resultingMoveY = $move[1]/($moves*$inverseCoefStrenth);
$this->nodes[$i][0]+=$resultingMoveX;
$this->nodes[$i][1]+=$resultingMoveY;
}
}
}


public function scale($iterations, $coefIncrease=0) {
$basicCoef=1;
for($i=0; $i<$iterations; $i++) {
$this->iterate($basicCoef);
//echo $this->getRSquared();
//echo " | ";

$basicCoef+=$coefIncrease;
}
}

public function coordsAsString() {
$coords = array();
foreach($this->nodes as $node) {
$coords[]="[{$node[0]}, {$node[1]}]";
}

$res = join(", ",$coords);
return "[$res]";
}

public function printCoords($pattern='[%X,%Y,"%LABEL"]') {
$coords = array();
foreach($this->nodes as $node) {
$x = $node[0];
$y = $node[1];
$label = $node[2];
$res = str_replace('%X', $x, $pattern);
$res = str_replace('%Y', $y, $res);
$res = str_replace('%LABEL', $label, $res);
$coords[]=$res;
}

$res = join(", ",$coords);
return "[$res]";
}

public function pointsCoords() {
$coords = array();
foreach($this->nodes as $node) {
$res['x'] = round($node[0]*100);
$res['y'] = round($node[1]*100);
$res['label'] = $node[2];
$coords[] = $res;
}
return $coords;
}

}
```